# Integral of Product of Bessel functions of different kind

Tags: special-functions, inner-products, bessel-functions

The problem:
-The integral of Bessel functions of different kind are not well placed among the literature. There is no clarification of how this integral works:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{r}Y_{m}(\alpha_{1}z)J_{m}(\alpha_{2}z)z dz
\end{equation}
I arrived at this integral working on a particular solution for a quasi-linear wave operator during my research.

Obs: I tried to find something related on the works of Watson, Lebedev, Korenev and Gray et al but to no avail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22.E4), when $\alpha_1\ne\alpha_2$,
\begin{equation}
 \int z Y_{m}\left(\alpha_1z\right)J_{m}(\alpha_2z)\mathrm{d}z=\frac{z%
\left(\alpha_1Y_{m+1}\left(\alpha_1z\right)J_{m}(\alpha_2z)-\alpha_2Y_{%
m}\left(\alpha_1z\right)J_{m+1}(\alpha_2z)\right)}{\alpha_1^{2}-\alpha_2^{2}}
\end{equation} 
The value of this antiderivative is non zero at $z=0$. Indeed, for $z\to 0$, retaining the leading term 
\begin{align}
J_n(z)&\sim \frac{1}{n!}\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)^n\\
Y_n(z)&\sim-\frac{(n-1)!}{\pi}\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)^{-n}\text{ for } n>0
\end{align}
It exists thus a non-zero contribution of the term $zY_{m+1}\left(\alpha_1z\right)J_{m}(\alpha_2z)$:
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{z\to 0} z\alpha_1Y_{m+1}\left(\alpha_1z\right)J_{m}(\alpha_2z)=-\frac{2}{\pi}\left( \frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1} \right)^m
\end{equation} 
Then,
\begin{align}
  \int_0^r z Y_{m}&\left(\alpha_1z\right)J_{m}(\alpha_2z)\mathrm{d}z=\\
&\frac{r%
\left(\alpha_1Y_{m+1}\left(\alpha_1r\right)J_{m}(\alpha_2r)-\alpha_2Y_{%
m}\left(\alpha_1r\right)J_{m+1}(\alpha_2r)\right)}{\alpha_1^{2}-\alpha_2^{2}}+\frac{2}{\pi}\left( \frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1} \right)^m\frac{1}{\alpha_1^{2}-\alpha_2^{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Enta, but I can not figure out how did you perform the second integral...! Specifically, the last term below:                                                                     \begin{align}
 \frac{2}{\pi}\left( \frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1} \right)^m\frac{1}{\alpha_1^{2}-\alpha_2^{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for correcting the typo. I added the details for obtaining the $z=0$  value of the antiderivative in the answer.

Comment: I think now that the question is fully answered. Thanks, Enta!