# Integral of the product of Bessel functions of different kinds, but with same argument

Tags: integration, special-functions, bessel-functions

I am looking to finding the solution to indefinite integrals
\begin{align}
\int z J_m(a z) Y_m(a z)\, \text{d}z,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\int z I_m(a z) K_m(a z)\, \text{d}z
\end{align}

I know that there are solutions to these when the arguments of these Bessel functions are different, such as the solution posted in [Integral of Product of Bessel functions of different kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2479379/integral-of-product-of-bessel-functions-of-different-kind).
Those solutions, though, are singular when the arguments are the same, as is the case I am asking for here.

Are there any ways to get a solution for these integrals? We can assume that $m$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We begin with the indefinite integral

$$\begin{align}
\int z Z_m(\alpha z)B_m(\beta z)\,dz=\frac{
\beta z Z_{m}(\alpha z)B_{m-1}(\beta z)-\alpha z Z_
{m-1}(\alpha z)B_m(\beta z)}{\alpha^{2}-\beta^{2}}\tag1
\end{align} 
$$

for $\alpha \ne \beta$ where $Z_m$ and $B_m$ are arbitrary Bessel functions.

While the left-hand side $(1)$ is well-behaved for $\alpha=\beta$, the right-hand side is *not* of indeterminate form.  The apparent discrepancy is reconciled by remembering that $(1)$ is an indefinite integral.  Addition of an appropriate constant with respect to $z$ to the right-hand side of $(1)$ results in an indeterminate form.

Let $V$ be defined by the limit

$$\begin{align}
V&=\lim_{\alpha\to\beta}\left(\beta z Z_{m}(\alpha z)B_{m-1}(\beta z)-\alpha z Z_
{m-1}(\alpha z)B_m(\beta z)\right)\\\\
&=\beta z \left(Z_{m}(\beta z)B_{m-1}(\beta z)- Z_{m-1}(\beta z)B_m(\beta z)\right)\tag2
\end{align}$$

The following Wronskians hold:

$$\begin{align}
J_{m}(\beta z)Y_{m-1}(\beta z)- J_{m-1}(\beta z)Y_m(\beta z)&=2/(\pi \beta z)\tag{3a}\\\\
H_{m}^{(1)}(\beta z)H_{m-1}^{(2)}(\beta z)- H_{m-1}^{(1)}(\beta z)H_m^{(2)}(\beta z)&=-4i/(\pi \beta z)\tag{3b}
\end{align}$$

Given $(3a)$ and $(3b)$, it is evident that $V$, as given on the right-hand side of $(2)$, is independent of $z$.  Hence, we subtract $V$ from the numerator of $(1)$ and obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int z Z_m(\alpha z)B_m(\beta z)\,dz=\frac{
\beta z Z_{m}(\alpha z)B_{m-1}(\beta z)-\alpha z Z_
{m-1}(\alpha z)B_m(\beta z)-V}{\alpha^{2}-\beta^{2}}\tag4
\end{align} 
$$

which is clearly of indeterminate form.

It is left as an exercise for the reader to evaluate the limit as $\alpha\to \beta$ of $(4)$ using L'Hospital's Rule to obtain the result

$$\begin{align}
\int z Z_m(\alpha z)B_m(\beta z)\,dz&=\frac12 z^2\left(Z_m(\beta z)B_m(\beta z)-Z_{m-1}(\beta z)B_{m-1}(\beta z)\right)\\\\&-\frac{mz}{2\beta}\left(Z_m(\beta z)B_{m-1}(\beta z)+Z_{m-1}(\beta z)B_{m}(\beta z)\right)
\end{align} 
$$